# Handling M/chip fast transactions

Tags: emv, verifone, mastercard

i'm doing m-tip transactions and I stuck on M-TIP05-USM.Test.01.Scenario.01f.
According to M-TIP 2.0 Build 225 Test Definition Reference after offline pin verification next should be "The Issuer Script command is sent after First GEN AC - [RA120]". 
I'm getting "In Second GEN AC, the terminal requests an AAC - [R3]"             Property: CONTACT.APDU(CLA=80,INS=AE)[2].COMMAND:BYTE.3.BIT.7-8
            Expected: '00'
            Received: '01'

- and transaction is approved. Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

On *I'm getting "In Second GEN AC, the terminal requests an AAC - [R3]"*

- When you do GEN AC, in reference control parameter, terminal will
  tell the chip what kind of cryptogram it expects. In your case it
  says terminal requests an  AAC(reference control parameter is 0x00.
  If you were expecting an ARQC, it should have been 0x80 or if a TC
  0x40( In case a CDA card, bit 5 also to be considered. Check the below picture from [EMV Book 3](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223)). **In your case
  you need to identify what caused your terminal to request an AAC**(
  which mean terminal did not want to go ahead with the transaction).

May be you can get something from TVR, match the TVR against TAC - Decline (Terminal action code).

On *and transaction is approved. Any advices?*

- An AAC returned transaction should not be approved. How did you
  terminal consider the transaction approved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now i see that i make mistake.
In First GEN AC terminal request ARQC and it's fine, but in second GEN should be AAC request, but for now there is TC - and that is why transaction is approved. 
So the question is, what I have to change to terminal requests AAC in second GEN.

Comment: Understood why transaction got approved. Terminal will not just ask to decline without a reason. What is the case you are trying to test ?  Your case should explain clearly the reason for requesting an AAC. From where do you get this output - CONTACT.APDU(CLA=80,INS=AE)[2].COMMAND:BYTE.3.BIT.7-8 Expected: '00' Received: '01' ? Going as per this(check the image i posted) you should be requesting TC (not AAC) and your transaction is to be approved. Are you getting issuer script template 71 ? In that case you should send that before second Gen AC.